# rails array/hash from an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and i didn't get my code working with the array and hashes combination.

I have view with a @ftp_accounts[p.id].each:

```
- current_user.packets.each do |p|
  .row
    .widget.col-6
      .widget-header
        = fa_icon 'info'
        FTP-Accounts für das Paket: #{ p.name }
      .widget-body
        .widget-title
          Sie haben ##USED_FTP_ACCOUNTS## von #{ p.ftp_accs } genutzt.
        %p
          Um einen FTP-Account Ihrem Paket hinzuzufügen, klicken Sie bitte&nbsp;
          %a{ href:'' }>hier
          \.

        %table
          %thead
            %tr
              %th #
              %th Benutzer
              %th Kommentar
              %th Verzeichnis
              %th Quota
              %th Aktion
          %tbody
            - if @ftp_accounts[p.id].nil?
              %tr
            - else
              - @ftp_accounts[p.id].each do |ftp_acc|
                %tr
                  %td
                    = ftp_acc.id
                  %td
                    = ftp_acc.username
                  %td
                    = ftp_acc.comment
                  %td
                    = ftp_acc.dir
                  %td
                    = number_to_human_size(ftp_acc.quota_size)
                  %td asd
```

With `- @ftp_accounts[p.id].each do |ftp_acc|` I want to display all entries from my @ftp_accounts[p.id] array.

I get with `= @ftp_accounts[p.id].inspect` with this output:

```
{2=>#<FtpAccount id: 2, username: "example_2", status: 1, password: "88ea39439e74fa27c09a4fc0bc8ebe6d00978392", uid: 2000, gid: 2000, dir: "/home/test", ul_bandwidth: 100, dl_bandwidth: 100, comment: "Jop", ipaccess: "*", quota_size: 20, quota_files: 0, user_id: 1, packet_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

and I want my two ftp-accounts:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<FtpAccount id: 1, username: "example", status: 1, password: "a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3", uid: 2000, gid: 2000, dir: "/home/customer/ftp60047", ul_bandwidth: 500, dl_bandwidth: 500, comment: "SEEDS ACCOUNT 2GB", ipaccess: "*", quota_size: 2048, quota_files: 0, user_id: 1, packet_id: 1, created_at: "2015-05-27 15:34:36", updated_at: "2015-05-27 15:34:36">, #<FtpAccount id: 2, username: "example_2", status: 1, password: "88ea39439e74fa27c09a4fc0bc8ebe6d00978392", uid: 2000, gid: 2000, dir: "/home/test", ul_bandwidth: 100, dl_bandwidth: 100, comment: "Jop", ipaccess: "*", quota_size: 20, quota_files: 0, user_id: 1, packet_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

My Controller:

```
  def index
    @ftp_accounts = Hash.new

    current_user.ftp_accounts.to_ary.each do |ftp_acc|
      @ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id] = Hash.new
      @ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id][ftp_acc.id] = Hash.new
      @ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id][ftp_acc.id] = ftp_acc
    end
  end
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packets, :join_table => :users_packets, dependent: :destroy

  # BackUp
  has_many :backups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ftp_accounts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and my ftp_account.rb

```
class FtpAccount < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :packet
end
```

and my packet.rb

```
class Packet < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_packets
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller logic is the problem:

```
  def index
    @ftp_accounts = Hash.new

    current_user.ftp_accounts.to_ary.each do |ftp_acc|
      @ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id] = Hash.new # <-- this line is a problem
      @ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id][ftp_acc.id] = Hash.new
      @ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id][ftp_acc.id] = ftp_acc
    end
  end
```

The first line inside the loop will wipe out everything that was put into the variable in previous iterations if they share the same `packet_id`.

You can change this to:

```
@ftp_accounts[ftp_acc.packet_id] ||= Hash.new
```

Note: the second line inside the loop does nothing, because you're setting a value to a new Hash, then immediately overwriting it with `ftp_acc`.

Comment: thanks :) I didn't find the problem or any solution on the internet.